# Sencha Touch+Phonegap+Android Reference Error in application

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I followed official Sencha learning tutorial to setup my first phonegap app with sencha touch give on this [link](http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/).

And here's my `index.html` code -

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Contacts</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/touch/sencha-touch-debug.js"></script>
 <link href="lib/touch/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" rel="stylesheet"
type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
/* Ext.application({
    name : "DemoApp",
    launch : function() {
        console.log("App launch");
    }
}); */
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", DemoApp.launch, false);    
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
  </html>
```

And my `app/app.js` contains -

```
Ext.application({
name: 'DemoApp',
launch: function() {
    this.launched = true;
    this.mainLaunch();
},
mainLaunch: function() {
    if (!device || !this.launched) {return;}
    console.log('mainLaunch');
}
});
```

All the paths to the script are absolutely correct but still I get following error.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: DemoApp is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:19`

I also tried putting `app.js` in `index.html` itself but above error still persists. Sencha js and css are included correctly as I'm not getting any error regarding `Ext` not defined etc etc.

What else could be the reason. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
```

should be

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
```